# Criteria Builder query LIKE in json field

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, criteria-api

I am trying to build a query with Criteria Builder(LIKE), to look for a string in JSONARRAY field like this:

```
    [
      {
         "family_class": "Electric",
         "family_name": "lightBulb"
       },
      {
         "family_class": "Others",
         "family_name": "Oil"
       }  
     ]
```

one option would be to look for the family_name attribute, or maybe check if it contains the string there.

```
    if (residues != null && residues.length > 0) {


            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

            for (String residue : residues) {
                predicates.add(cb.like(root.get("jsonColumn"), residue.toLowerCase()));

            } 


            cr.select(root).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));

            Query<SyncCollectionPoints> q = sess.createQuery(cr);

            List<SyncCollectionPoints> result= q.getResultList();
```

This is the error i get:

```
Unrecognized token 'oil': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
```

All i want is to return the lines that have that string in the jsonColumn field.

Comment: What is your `root` entity, can you show it?

Comment: Hello @code Tester could you help me, with my case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60807531/how-to-convert-query-function-jsonb-contains-to-jpa-hibernate-criteriabuilder

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work like this:

```
@Formula(value = "lower(jsonColumn::text)")
private String residuesToSearch;
```

just a simple cast did the trick