# How to convert query function jsonb_contains to JPA/hibernate Criteriabuilder

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jsonb

Hallo guys i need some help to my case,

i want to convert this native query to predicate JPA,

i have query like this on postgresql :
table user :

```
INT id -> example data : 1
VARCHAR name -> example data : 'ronaldo'
jsonb categoryId -> example data : [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and query :

```
SELECT * FROM user where categoryId @> '[3,4,5]'::jsonb
```

and i have tried with parameter integer 3, like this but still error:

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
Expression<Boolean> contains = criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_contains", Boolean.class,root.get("categoryId"), criteriaBuilder.literal(3));
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.and(),contains));
return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
}
```

anyone can help me,
thankyou